# Swift - View not displaying/updating controls even though they are visible

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiactivityindicatorview

Apologies for the horrible title, but I really couldn't think of any better way to put it.  My code is below:

```
@IBAction func btnSaveTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    println("Save Button Pressed")
    self.StartAI()
    self.btnSave.enabled = false
    self.AnimateButton(sender)

    var booContinueWithSend:Bool = true
    (Continues)
```

When I run the above code, there is no change to the controls on the screen.  I have stepped through the code and each line, there is no change.  Even for the `btnSave.enabled`, there is no change.  I have confirmed through `po`ing the console debugger that the button is NOT enabled, and yet it still displays as if it is.  And yes, I have set it to visibly change depending on state (code below):

```
self.btnSave.setTitleColor(conButtonTextColour, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
self.btnSave.setTitleColor(conButtonTextColourDisabled, forState: UIControlState.Disabled)
```

where `conButtonTextColour` is `UIColor.blackColor` and `conButtonTextColourDisabled` is gray.

It also happens for my activity indicator, which I have tested manually successfully.  When I run the above code (`btnSaveTapped`), nothing happens (it doesn't display like it should).  I create the AI programmatically here:

```
func CreateAI() {
    let conAIViewHeightWidth:CGFloat = 100
    let conHeightWidth:CGFloat = 50

    self.aiView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    self.view.addSubview(self.aiView)
    self.aiView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.3)
    self.aiView.layer.cornerRadius = 10

    var constraintViewHeight:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.aiView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: conAIViewHeightWidth)
    var constraintViewWidth:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.aiView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: conAIViewHeightWidth)
    self.aiView.addConstraints([constraintViewHeight, constraintViewWidth])

    var constraintViewX:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.aiView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    var constraintViewY:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.aiView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    self.view.addConstraints([constraintViewX, constraintViewY])


    self.aiActivityIndicator.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    self.aiView.addSubview(self.aiActivityIndicator)
    self.aiActivityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge


    var constraintX:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.aiActivityIndicator, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.aiView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    var constraintY:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.aiActivityIndicator, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.aiView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    self.view.addConstraints([constraintX, constraintY])

    self.aiActivityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    self.aiActivityIndicator.startAnimating()

    StopAI()
}
```

Here are my two routines to start and stop the AI respectively.  Because the AI is a subview of `aiView` I just hide or unhide that.  However, with these problems, I decided to get super safe and make sure I was unhiding and enabling the AI.

```
func StartAI() {
    self.aiView.hidden = false
    self.aiActivityIndicator.hidden = false
    self.aiActivityIndicator.startAnimating()
    println("Started AI")
}

func StopAI() {
    self.aiView.hidden = true
    println("Stopped AI")
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This maybe because of constraints. It is possible that you have added constraints to some elements and left some without constraints which makes view non interactive

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

implement this when all the changes are made